# Modifying android app for tablet

Tags: android

I currently have an app I'm working on that is made specifically for android phones(layout etc all looks fine on phone) but I want to totally re-skin my app giving it a totally different feel. I have all the fragments set up and are added to the main gui activity in onCreate(). Is there a way that I can create new fragments and add them specifically if someone is using the app on a tablet? Or do I need to start from scratch and just reuse my model files?? If someone could point me to some good resources that would be great :)

Comment: You can try to read about Dependency Injection. I'm not so familiar with it but there you can dynamically inject classes into classes, functions and even constructor methods.

Comment: The second one suggestion is that you probably need to lear about theming your app, and about layouts. in fact android catches up the layout the mobile device is used, checking it's size of screen.

Comment: Well how about adding a new activity in my "layout-swxxx" folder? Could i set up java to only call that in the event of it being used on a tablet?

Comment: I dont understand clearly what do you want to get with this. You can add new layout for big screens and this could be totally different from the phone's layout. in your code, you just check in onCreate function, what type of screen user has. and applying that layout in setContentView, which you want. because of your code depends of element names in layout, you must use `if` constructions to work with totally different layouts inside of your app

Comment: But if you use one style for all types of screens, you dont need to rewrite your app. just create layouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question !

Android is well designed to tackle the the same fragments on different layouts.
What I do usually is to add my fragments in the xml layouts. 
And then use the different resolution folders. It works pretty well.

But if you want to have specific code for tablets or phones and sometimes it's necessary it's more difficult.
I usually use a trick. 
Create a folder values-xlarge in your res folder and a file layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

In the normal values folder do the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

And then your create method, you can have specific code.

```
if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet)) {
  // specific tablet code 
}
```

Hope it'll help !

Comment: What will you have for TV? :P

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid your question is too broad as this targets overall app design and functionality, so I'll try to answer as general as possible :)

Don't make a separate project for tablet only as it will be a nightmare to maintain the code. Since you started the project using fragments then you should use those for tablets as well; but you need to re-design the current app only for tablets and check how existing fragments will look and behave on tablet. This means you need to step back and take a second look at your app and think how it should behave and look on tablet.

Each of your fragments will probably need to be re-designed for tablets, but the good news is that you should probably change the layout XML only.

There are a couple of very helpful articles on the developers section ([this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) or [this](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html)). Also the [Android developers blogspot](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/) had some interesting articles on this specific topic ([this](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2013/04/update-on-tablet-app-guidelines-and.html) or [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2013/04/tablet-optimization-tips-in-google-play.html)). Each of those contain other links to other very helpful articles.

Good luck! you'll need it ...

Answer (score 0):

The better option is that design the application according to the hdpi sizes or define your owns styles in style folder